# Can I include Aadhar details in android app by getting the aadhar number

Tags: android

Sir I am doing a project on Android app development. Can I include Aadhar number and fetch details of the person by it? If so how? Please give me the code.

Comment: Please remember that such questions would rarely fetch any answers. You need to show what you have done. Show some code. Give much details. Only then people would be able to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody is going to write your app for you. You need to go through the documentation and understand the whole process before attempting to make such app. Even if somebody gives you some code, you will get stuck somewhere down the line if you don't understand the whole process properly.

This is a good place to start: [aadhaar_authentication_api_1_6.pdf](https://uidai.gov.in/images/FrontPageUpdates/aadhaar_authentication_api_1_6.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
do
{
    System.Out.PrintLine("I have to do some homework first!");
} while (true);
```